# error in PHP program ,Why don't this correctly run?

Tags: php, messaging

`<select name="filtering">`
`<option value="a">a</option>`
`<option value="b">b</option>`

```
if (isset($_POST['filtering']) == "a") {
    $stmt = prepare("SELECT * FROM user_posts ORDER BY post_time DESC LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset");
}

if (isset($_POST['filtering']) == "b") {
    $stmt = prepare("SELECT * FROM user_posts ORDER BY post_time ASC LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset");
}
```

Comment: Isset returns true/false

Answer (score -1):

Isset will return only true or false

```
if (isset($_POST['filtering'])&&($_POST['filtering']=="a")){
    $stmt = prepare("SELECT * FROM user_posts ORDER BY post_time DESC LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset");
}

if (isset($_POST['filtering'])&&($_POST['filtering']=="b")) {
    $stmt = prepare("SELECT * FROM user_posts ORDER BY post_time ASC LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset");
}
```

Comment: It can't be a and b

Comment: why it will return a or b? please clarify?